# Gitlab Access Token With Okta

Tags: bash, ubuntu, gitlab, okta

I am not sure if this is the correct forum to ask on but:

I had Gitlab access tokens working for some automated bash scripts that run daily via cron.

Then we turned on Okta and now my automated scripts do not work. Specifically, I have to run them manually, authenticate manually via the link it spits out, and then my script is authenticated for the day and will run properly.

I do not have control over Okta so I'm not sure of the options and cannot find much information online. What are my options here? Is there a way to extend the session lifetime? Is it possible to create an account that can authenticate in some other manner? Do I need to switch to built in Gitlab devops tools? How have others solved this problem?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to use a [Project Access Token](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/settings/project_access_tokens.html) instead of a personal access token.